ServiceImpl defined in a dependent jar library is not found by spring in MainApplication
I have created a springboot application which will serve as a library for my MainApplication. This library has some service class, repository class and entity, basically an independent feature which can be used my multiple applications. My flow looks something like this:
Entity:
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.FieldDefaults;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UuidGenerator;

import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = lombok.AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Builder
@Table(name = "alert_app_integration")
public class AppIntegration {
    @Id
    @UuidGenerator
    UUID id;

    @Column(name = "workspace_id", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(150)")
    String workspaceId;

    @Column(name = "channel", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50)")
    String channel;

    @Column(name = "config", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    String config;

    @Column(name = "active", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN")
    boolean active;
}

Service and its implementation:
public interface AppIntegrationService {
}

@Service
@Slf4j
public class AppIntegrationServiceImpl implements AppIntegrationService {

    private final AppIntegrationRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public AppIntegrationServiceImpl(AppIntegrationRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
}

@Repository
public interface AppIntegrationRepository extends JpaRepository<AppIntegration, UUID> {
}

To test locally, I am publishing the library's jar to mavenLocal and gradle looks like this
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'xx.xx.xxx'
version = '0.0.14'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
    compileOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}

To make sure that the MainApplication don't have to bother about component scanning, entity scanning etc, I created a customConfig to do all this
package xx.xx.xxx;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories*(basePackages = "xx.xx.xxx.alerts.repository")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "xx.xx.xxx")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "xx.xx.xxx.alerts.model")
public class PlatformUtilConfig {
}

And also created META-INF/spring.factories so AutoConfiguration takes care of stuff
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\ xx.xx.xxx.PlatformUtilConfig
When I am trying to use the library in my MainApplication like:
@Service
@Slf4j
public class AlertServiceImpl  implements AlertService {
    private final AppIntegrationService appIntegrationService;
    private final UserConfig userConfig;

    @Autowired
    public AlertServiceImpl(AppIntegrationService appIntegrationService, UserConfig userConfig) {
        this.appIntegrationService = appIntegrationService;
        this.userConfig = userConfig;
    }
}

I get few variations of issues like
Parameter 0 of constructor in xx.xx.xxxxx.platform.service.alert.AlertServiceImpl required a bean of type 'xx.xx.xxx.alerts.service.AppIntegrationService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'xx.xx.xxx.alerts.service.AppIntegrationService' in your configuration.

I tried to jumble the @EntityScan, EnableJpaRepositories, @ComponentScan within MainApplication and library, upon which I started getting something like
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appIntegrationRepository' defined in xx.xx.xxx.alerts.repository.AppIntegrationRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on MainApplication: Not a managed type: class xx.xx.xxx.alerts.model.AppIntegration



you have to make sure you are scanning (with @ComponentScan) the base package of the library you are trying to use. Alternatively, you can redeclare it as bean in you app

The use of spring.factories has changed long time ago for auto configuration classes use a file named org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports instead. This file should contain only the name of the auto-configuration classes. Which is also explained in the documentation

The use of spring.factories has changed long time ago for auto configuration classes use a file named org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports in the META-INF/spring directory instead. This file should contain only the name of the auto-configuration classes.
xx.xx.xxx.PlatformUtilConfig

This is also explained in the documentation
